# AspNetCore 3.0 (upgraded from 2.2) routes seem to break when Controller Method has Async suffix

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I upgraded my project to Core 3.0 from 2.2 and everything seems to work well, except one `get JSON request`. I have the following `Js` code doing an `Ajax` request to the Home controller:

```
    var isLastPage = false;
    var incidentModel = {
        incidents: ko.observableArray([]),
        getIncidents: function(a) {
            var self = this;
            //var $incdiv = $('#incidentsList');
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("AjaxPageAsync", "Home")', { page: page++, user: user, type: type }, function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                self.incidents(self.incidents().concat(data));
                if (data[0].IsLastPage) {
                    isLastPage = true;
                }
                a();
            });
        }
    }
```

The Home controller is like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AjaxPageAsync([FromQuery] string type, [FromQuery] string user, [FromQuery] int? page)
{
       //Get some json data
       return Json(Incident);
}
```

As you may tell, I'm using knockout (version 3.5.0 & jquery 3.3.0) which both are working fine on other pages. However, the `getJSON` request in the js code above is returning a 404:

```
GET https://localhost:44366/Home/AjaxPageAsync?page=1&user=&type=&_=1575386778917 404
```

The debug output looks similar:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44366/Home/AjaxPageAsync?page=1&user=&type=&_=1575386536876
```

The 2.2 version is identical and works fine. I thought it might be the number appended onto the end of the url, but that exists in 2.2 as well.

At this point, I'm thinking it's a problem with the syntax of my `AjaxPageAsync` task in the controller, but not sure what it should be.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: What attributes does your controller class have? And what about the action method?

Comment: Your URL is wrong. Even in 2.2 the URL should be `AjaxPage`, not `AjaxPageAsync`. Did you use routing attributes to expose the `Async` suffix, or a custom route? Post the controller and method attributes at least. You should probably post the routing configuration code from `Startup`

Comment: Please post the controller and action attributes, along with the route configuration. The URL used is *not* typical. People can't guess what's wrong with custom routing configuration they can't see

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I'm not using any attributes, what I posted is what I'm using and 2.2 must be compensating to some degree? I'll also try removing the Async portion and see what happens. It's the default new endpoint routing. I'm not using anything custom on that front. I basically created a new 3.0 project and pasted the default routing from that into this project which all seems to be working except for this json request... hopefully that answers all questions? I'll add some more controller code, but there's not much else there... just DI and `public ActionResult Index ()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8998, in .NET Core 3.0 `Async` is trimmed from Action name. Your endpoint is available at `/Home/AjaxPage`. You can change this behaviour by replacing

```
services.AddControllers();
```

with

```
services.AddControllers(options => options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false);
```

in `ConfigureServices` method, or just use the new routes

Comment: That's it. I actually just removed the "Async" portion of the name in the json request and task name. That was the original name to begin with and when I added an `await` call (way back in 2.2) it auto-renamed the task (but only in the controller), so I just went with that in the javascript as well. Anyway, many thanks. Killed hours on that in what I thought was just a name.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with an elimination of getJson and what not, run a manual Postman or Curl against the endpoint to create the simplest reproducible use case to troubleshoot.

If it's still 404, you know its the configuration side of AspNetCore.

If it's not 404, you have a problem specific with an Ajax call to NetCore 3.0. That can narrow the scope of what you are searching for (and thereby your Google parameters).

My guess to the actual problem is the routing you have setup is not working or configuration has shifted in NetCore3. This usually happens when you had a routing setup in NetCore 1.0/1.2, years later migrated an example to NetCore 2.0 which was backwards compatible, years later again, bumped to NetCore 3.0, and NetCore 3 may not exactly support that routing configuration without some additional hoops to jump through.

Try creating a simple `helloworld` in the same controller and wiring it up. If that works you have essentially isolated the issues to the controller/method and the routing.

If didn't support it at all, it wouldn't compile though...

...so swings and roundabouts!

Also, it's Task but you are only returning Result... this is probably a simplified example but make sure you are returning/awaiting correctly.

Looking at specifically Async method tags with AspNetCore3 and there is an MvcOption that SuppressesAsyncSuffixActionName and is `true` by default in AspNetCore 3.0 (looks like [Piotr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6317985/piotr-%c5%81azarczyk) found it first!)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.suppressasyncsuffixinactionnames?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Even in 2.2 , the method `AjaxPageAsync` would surface as `AjaxPage`. The OP would have to modify the default routes to expose the `Async` suffix

Comment: I imagine they're probably awaiting an async call somewhere in the controller method. That just wasn't included in the post for brevity.

Comment: I agree with @MattU, it probably just appears an issue in example. I also have Async in my Async methods in my Controllers in my personal website - so it does work, but I do use custom routes so my hunch is that is the possible problem. We won't know without seeing the actual route + controller.

Comment: As I mentioned above and as Housecat wrote, nothing was custom (unless VS changed it for me somewhere). When I added an `await` call, it literally renamed the task for me (back in 2.2) with the `Async` suffix, but in the controller only. Then I just changed it in the javascript to fix the issue it created. I never would have used (or even known of) those `Async` suffixes, but assumed it was doing it for a reason. Thanks guys for your input and help.